# Как настроить Magento2

Tags: magento

Решил попробовать magento 2, но возникла проблема после установки. В админку не пускает: бесконечный редирект. Таблицу с настройками смотрел, кэш чистил, mode выставлен в production. В дополнение ко всему не отображается фронт часть. Просто пустой экран. Перепробовал все, что можно. PHP 7.2, Apache 2.4
В какую сторону рыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переключитесь в **developer mode**:

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
>
> php bin/magento cache:clear

1. **Production mode** не выбрасывает ексепшены на экран. Подробнее об отличиях режимов [смотрите тут](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html).

Дополнительно в файле **`app/bootstrap.php`** найдите строчку **`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`**. Раскомментируйте её (она в начале файла), это даст вам возможность смотреть ошибки, выбрасываемые **php**.

2. Выставьте/проверьте [права на файлы и папки](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions).
3. Up to you **;)**